# React Native Build Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 How to fix this Error?

Tags: react-native

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Failed to find Build Tools revision 30.0.3

- Try:
  up.
  Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Failed to find Build Tools revision 30.0.3

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

When i build the react-native-cli app using npx react-native run-android the error get shows. How can i fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the error message `Failed to find Build Tools revision 30.0.3`, you need to first download and install the build tools `v30.0.3`. You can do that by opening the `SDK manager` and navigating to `SDK Tools` as follows:

[image]

Now, select the version `30.0.3` and install the same.